# Django firebase phone auth

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, python-phonenumber

Is there module for Django which works with Firebase and can use Firebase to send SMS to phone? I use [django-phone-auth](https://pypi.org/project/django-phone-auth/), but it's not working with Firebase. Thank you.

Comment: Please read: [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)